# Each of my media queries is getting a parse error when I try to validate css

Tags: css, error, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate a css file. Every one of my media queries is getting a parse error.

I have checked and I do not have any missing curly brackets, colons, or semi-colons.

I also set the W3C Validator to validate CSS 3.

Below is a sample of a media query that is getting a parse error:

```
@media and (min-width: 600px){
    h1.page-titles{
        font-size: 3.5em;
        margin-top: 25px;
        }
    }
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Also tried without the `and` in the first line, as well as adding a semi-colon after 600px. All give parse errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example code from my own CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {

.cont-left{
    width: 85%;
}

}
```

You will notice the addition of the term screen.

Comment: @as_whitley I am glad I could help! I was sure it was something simple. We all miss stuff from time to time. I have seen bad code on otherwise excellent sites that are very reliable. It happens to all of us. Cheers!!